# Jackson Cannot Find a (Map) Key Deserializer for Path?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a strange issue where I have a HashMap that I serialize for later use on the disk.

It is a `HashMap<Path, ConverterMetadata>` the `ConverterMetadata` being a custom class that I wrote to keep track of music file metadata.

The ConverterMetadata appears to have proper tags and in my testing I have confirmed that Jackson can write and read `Map<Path, String>` instances, so I'm not entirely sure what is happening here, and why it says that it is breaking on the key (Path) object.

Here is the exception, the class, the JSON outputted, and the method that reads/writes it:

**The Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot find a (Map) Key deserializer for type [simple type, class java.nio.file.Path]
 at [Source: (File); line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1452)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._handleUnknownKeyDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:599)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findKeyDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:168)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findKeyDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:500)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.createContextual(MapDeserializer.java:248)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleSecondaryContextualization(DeserializationContext.java:682)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:482)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:4191)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4010)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2922)
    at com.protonmail.sarahszabo.stellar.conversions.SpaceBridge.initBridge(SpaceBridge.java:151)
    at com.protonmail.sarahszabo.stellar.StellarMode$2.start(StellarMode.java:87)
    at com.protonmail.sarahszabo.stellar.Main.stellarConversion(Main.java:203)
    at com.protonmail.sarahszabo.stellar.Main.main(Main.java:77)
```

**ConverterMetadata Class:**

```
/**
 * A representation of .opus metadata. Used in concordance with a
 * {@link StellarOPUSConverter}. All fields are immutable.
 */
public final class ConverterMetadata {

    /**
     * The default metadata instance.
     */
    public static final ConverterMetadata DEFAULT_METADATA = new ConverterMetadata("Unknown Artist",
            "Unknown Title", Main.FULL_PROGRAM_NAME, LocalDate.MAX, StellarGravitonField.newPath(""), Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    @JsonProperty
    private final String artist;
    @JsonProperty
    private final String title;
    @JsonProperty
    private final String createdBy;
    @JsonProperty
    private final LocalDate stellarIndexDate;
    @JsonProperty
    private final Path albumArtPath;
    @JsonProperty
    private final int bitrate;

    /**
     * Constructs a new {@link ConverterMetadata} with the specified arguments.
     *
     *
     * @param artist The artist for this track
     * @param title The title of this track
     * @param createdBy The program that created this track/last modified this
     * track
     * @param date The date this track was created
     * @param albumArtPath The path to the album art
     * @param bitrate The bitrate of the track
     */
    @JsonCreator
    public ConverterMetadata(@JsonProperty(value = "artist") String artist,
            @JsonProperty(value = "title") String title, @JsonProperty(value = "createdBy") String createdBy,
            @JsonProperty(value = "stellarIndexDate") LocalDate date, @JsonProperty(value = "albumArtPath") Path albumArtPath,
            @JsonProperty(value = "bitrate") int bitrate) {
        //Do Consructor Stuff Here
    }
}
```

**Code that Writes/Reads from the Ledger File AKA initBridge():**

```
Map<Path, ConverterMetadata> LIBRARY_LEDGER = new HashMap<>();
//Earlier in the code, write ledger, to disk
MAPPER.writeValue(LIBRARY_LEDGER_PATH.toFile(), LIBRARY_LEDGER);
//Later we read the ledger    
Map<Path, ConverterMetadata> previousLedger = MAPPER.readValue(LIBRARY_LEDGER_PATH.toFile(),
                        new TypeReference<HashMap<Path, ConverterMetadata>>() {
                });
                LIBRARY_LEDGER.putAll(previousLedger);
```

**JSON in the File:**

```
{"/home/sarah/Music/Indexing/Playlists/Best Playlist/Spiral.opus":{"artist":"Vangelis","title":"Spiral","createdBy":"Stellar OPUS Conversion Library 1.4α","stellarIndexDate":[2018,7,23],"albumArtPath":"file:///tmp/Stellar%20OPUS%20Converter%20Temporary%20Directory15723231348656772389/ReIndexing/Spiral.png","bitrate":320},"/home/sarah/Music/Indexing/Playlists/Finished/Aphelion.opus":{"artist":"Scandroid","title":"Aphelion","createdBy":"Stellar OPUS Conversion Library 1.4α","stellarIndexDate":[2018,8,8],"albumArtPath":"file:///tmp/Stellar%20OPUS%20Converter%20Temporary%20Directory15723231348656772389/ReIndexing/Aphelion.png","bitrate":320}
```

**POM:**

```
    <properties>
  ...
  <!-- Use the latest version whenever possible. -->
  <jackson.version>2.9.8</jackson.version>
  ...
</properties>

<dependencies>
  ...
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  ...
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Check this link. https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1688

Comment: @Sambit But I can deserialize `Path` instances. I tried it using the same mapper with the same config in a small test method.

Comment: Can you post the class com.protonmail.sarahszabo.stellar.conversions.SpaceBridge.initBridge?

Comment: @Sambit My bad, the "Code that Writes/Reads from the Ledger File:" section is initBridge(). I also, simplified the POM to what it is now.

Comment: No problem, it happens sometimes.

Comment: Non related question, why is your LocaleDate i.e stellarIndexDate  an array? How is that getting read? Is it that, the ConverterMetadata deserialization itself is broken?

Comment: @Optional This program was made in the Java 8 days, and was using an older Jackson module to serialize the Date. I've since compiled to Java 12 and used a more recent version of Jackson and re-generated the JSON file. The `LocalDateTime` is serialized however `ObjectMapper` thinks is best using the default settings (I don't touch `ObjectMapper` at all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement key deserialiser for `java.nio.file.Path` class. It could like below:

```
class PathKeyDeserializer extends KeyDeserializer {

    @Override
    public Object deserializeKey(String key, DeserializationContext ctxt) {
        return Paths.get(key);
    }
}
```

You can register it and use like in below example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.KeyDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<Path, String> path2String = new HashMap<>();
        path2String.put(Paths.get("user", "downloads"), "Downloads");
        path2String.put(Paths.get("home", "des"), "Desktop");

        SimpleModule nioModule = new SimpleModule();
        nioModule.addKeyDeserializer(Path.class, new PathKeyDeserializer());

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        mapper.registerModule(nioModule);

        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(path2String);
        System.out.println(json);

        path2String = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<HashMap<Path, String>>() {});
        System.out.println(path2String);
    }

}
```

Above code prints:

```
{
  "home/des" : "Desktop",
  "user/downloads" : "Downloads"
}
{home/des=Desktop, user/downloads=Downloads}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for the answer! Why do I have to do this though? Doesn't `Path` and `Map` have native Jackson support? It seems kind of strange that it can write it properly, but not read it.

Comment: @SarahSzabo, by default `Map` is supported by `Jackson` because it is use to ready any unknown `JSON Object`. For `Path` we need to create custom `key-deserialiser` because `Jackson` does not know how to create it from `String`. `Jackson` needs help for classes which do not have fit constructors or `Jackson` annotations. This is why we create modules and define all kinds of serialisers and deserialisers for given set of classes. For example, take a look at [JavaTimeModule](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datetime) which supports `Java 8` `Time` package.

Comment: If I'm using JDK 12 and are using ZonedDateTime and other java time classes, do I need to register the JavaTimeModule? Also, are there libraries of seralizers/deseriaizers for common classes such as `Path` or do I just have to make it? I'm kind of new to Jackson and are just trying to get the basics of it.

Comment: @SarahSzabo, yes you still need to use `JavaTimeModule` for `Java Time` class set. No, there is no predefined serialisers for classes like `Path`. [FasterXML](https://github.com/FasterXML) by default supports `POJO` classes and primitives. `Path` class is not an `POJO` and you need to create customer serialiser/deserialiser for it. You can find some implemented [modules on Github](https://github.com/FasterXML?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=module&type=&language=).